# Not able to locate element id of email() in login :error(Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Email"})

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

By clicking on login page it is going on login part but this email field it is not able to locate any path i have tried all possible ways of path,id,classname bt still it is unable to get the element of email.
The code is given below:

```
@Test
public void blankentries() 
{

//  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement email= driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));

    email.clear();
    email.sendKeys("");

    WebElement password= driver.findElement(By.id("password"));

    password.clear();
    password.sendKeys("");

    WebElement signinbutton= driver.findElement(By.className("button-1"));

    signinbutton.click();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with the another annotation like by name or classname. or try to do clean the project and after run the project and add priority in functions

```
WebElement email= driver.findElement(By.name("Email"));
email.clear();
email.sendKeys("");
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find an element is by Element's associated ID.

You can also try this:

```
//*[contains(@id,'Email')];
```